# Creating a single output file fom 3 csv files using Python

Tags: python, vlookup

I have 3 CSV files. Names are below

```
AD.csv
ID.csv
MD.csv

AD.csv
A.Net    ATVS
A&E HD  60 Days In
AXSTV    60 Days : Watch Along
BET HD   Behind Bars: Rookie Year
Bloomberg    Biggie: The Life of Notorious B.I.G.

ID.csv
I.Net  ITvs
AETVHD  60 Days In
AXSTV   60 Days : Watch Along 
BETHD    Behind Bars: Rookie Year
BLOOMHD Dog the Bounty Hunter

MD.csv
A.Net   I.Net
A&E HD  AETVHD
AXSTV   AXSTV
BET HD  BETHD
Bloomberg   BLOOMHD
```

In MD.csv, 'a.net' = 'I.net'
which means I have to map the data in 'atvs' with 'itvs' where MD.csv 'a.net = i.net'
I am new to write python script, can anyone help me to map this?

```
import csv
with open('E:/ad.csv', 'r') as lookuplist:
with open('E:/id.csv', 'r') as csvinput:
with open('vlookupout', 'w') as output:

reader = csv.reader(lookuplist)
reader2 = csv.reader(csvinput)
writer = csv.writer(output)

for 'itvs' in reader2:
for 'atvs' in reader:
if itvs[0] == atvs[0]:
itvs.append(atvs[1:])
writer.writerow(itvs)
```

Comment: a very easy way is to load the csv to a pandas dataframe and do a merge using the criteria you mentioned.

Comment: Is this really what your csv's look like exactly with the correct amount of spaces/spacing between them? For example: `BLOOMHD Dog the Bounty Hunter` only has one space between "BLOOMHD"  and "Dog the...". This wil be more difficult to import.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any dependency constraints, use `DataFrame` from the pandas library.

Using DataFrames, you can simply read and load the CSVs as tables.

```
ad = pd.read_csv('E:\ad.csv')
id = pd.read_csv('E:\id.csv')
```

... and perform joins/merge/aggregations on them.

```
result = pd.merge(ad,
             id[['I.Net', 'ITVs']],
             on='I.Net')
```

It'll be much easier and flexible as per your requirement.

Comment: This won't work. 'ITvs' is not present in ad. So you will have to map I.Net to A.net using MD.csv as well

Comment: Right, Thanks. I intended to give direction to the OP about the suggested approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

# read in the csv's
ad_df = pd.read_csv('AD.csv', sep=r'\s\s+', engine='python')
id_df = pd.read_csv('ID.csv', sep=r'\s\s+', engine='python')
md_df = pd.read_csv('MD.csv', sep=r'\s\s+', engine='python')

# Combine the csv's using MD.csv
result = pd.merge(ad_df,md_df[['A.Net', 'I.Net']], on='A.Net')
result = pd.merge(result,id_df[['I.Net', 'ITvs']], on='I.Net')

# in case you want to drop 'I.Net' add:
result.drop('I.Net', axis=1, inplace=True)

#export to csv:
result.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

Note: Your CSV's have some inconsistencies in the header names. I used the names in my script exactly as provided. 
As noted in my comment, your csv seperation looks off. I made one small change in the csv, by adding an extra space between "BLOOMHD" and "Dog the...".